# Is this approach safe to use?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm fairly new to working with SQL Server and ASP.NET so I'm worried about SQL injection or other threats. I have a FormView referencing a `SqlDataSource` where the `FormView` has code-behind logic preventing unauthorized users from making changes to the database. Is this approach safe to use:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT Ads.AdId, Ads.UserId, Ads.Title, Ads.Summary, Ads.Description, Ads.ImageId, Ads.Price, Ads.MapRadius, Ads.Latitude, Ads.Longitude, Users.UserName FROM Ads INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UserId = Ads.UserId WHERE ([AdID] = @AdID)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE Ads SET Title = @Title, Summary = @Summary, Description = @Description, Price = @Price, Ads.MapRadius = @MapRadius, Latitude = @Latitude, Longitude = @Longitude, DateModified = @DateModified WHERE ([AdID] = @AdID)" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="AdID" QueryStringField="Ad" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="Title" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Summary" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Description" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Price" DbType="Double" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="MapRadius" DbType="Double" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Latitude" DbType="Double" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="Longitude" DbType="Double" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="DateModified" DbType="DateTime" />
     </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Where the url may be something like:

```
domain.com/Display?Ad=314c226b-6dfd-4fd7-997b-2ec25d18c0c2
```

More specifically, my concern is with using query strings as a parameter. For a more general question, if I didn't use the `<UpdateParameters>` or the `<InsertParameters>` would there even be a risk of SQL injection when using an `asp:SqlDataSource`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the `<UpdateParameters>` and the `<InsertParameters>` is what is helping prevent SQL injection and you are correct in using them.

Comment: What if I was only selecting data and had no intention of updating, inserting, or deleting? ex: Using a GridView with a SqlDataSource and filtering the results by using a query string parameter to find specific data.

Comment: `SelectParameters` - using the parameters rather than embedding the variable directly in the SQL string is what combats the SQL injection.